# Linux AD workstations not populated in Domain Master Browser

Tags: windows-server-2008, samba, netbios

We have a mixed environment with a Windows 2008 Server as a DC and Linux/Windows/OS X workstations/servers joined to the domain. The problem  is the joins (domain memberships) are OK, browsing works, PAM authentication on Linux based on winbind works but some (not all) Linux computers are not showing in the master computer browser for the domain.

All of our Linux servers/ workstations are running CentOS 5.8/RHEL 5.8/ CentOS 6 or RHEL 6. This is the nbtstat output of a Linux server that works:

```
C:\Users\rchhetri>nbtstat -a xlxudt

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [10.0.0.200] Scope Id: []
NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
xLXUDT      <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
xLXUDT      <03>  UNIQUE      Registered
xLXUDT      <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
DOMAIN         <1E>  GROUP       Registered
DOMAIN         <00>  GROUP       Registered

MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00

C:\Users\rchhetri>net view \\Xlxudt
Shared resources at \\xlxudt

RHE Mainframe

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Data        Disk           Data
Data2       Disk           Data2
Data3       Disk           Data3
HOLD        Disk  Z:       Hold
pldfiles    Disk           pldfiles
ud72        Disk           ud72
vertex      Disk           vertex
The command completed successfully.
```

And this is for a server that does not populate the computer master browser:

```
C:\Users\rchhetri>nbtstat -a xlx0

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [10.0.0.200] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.

C:\Users\rchhetri>net view \\xlx0
Shared resources at \\xlx0

Samba Server Version 3.5.10-114.el6

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
homes       Disk           Home Directories
public      Disk           Public Stuff
rchhetri    Disk           Home Directories
xfer        Disk           All Users
The command completed successfully.
```

The samba configurations for both servers are same. We are also running a wins server in the DC. From our samba clients, this is for the one that works:

```
smbclient -L localhost -U rchhetri
Password: 
Domain=[x] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.33-3.39.el5_8]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    Data            Disk      Data
    Data2           Disk      Data2
    Data3           Disk      Data3
    HOLD            Disk      Hold
    ud72            Disk      ud72
    pldfiles        Disk      pldfiles
    vertex          Disk      vertex
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (RHE Mainframe)
Domain=[x] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.33-3.39.el5_8]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    xDC1              COPS
    xLXUDT            RHE Mainframe

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    x                 xDC1
```

And the one that does not work:

```
smbclient -L localhost -U rchhetri
Enter rchhetri's password: 
Domain=[x] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-114.el6]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    homes           Disk      Home Directories
    xfer            Disk      All Users
    public          Disk      Public Stuff
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba Server Version 3.5.10-114.el6)
    rchhetri        Disk      Home Directories
Domain=[x] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.5.10-114.el6]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

Our samba configs are same but the samba versions above are different (3.0 and 3.5). We have another Samba 3.5 domain member that works perfectly.

Steps that I have done:

1. Confirmed that both forward and reverse zones in the DNS of the
   domain are populated.
2. Even added static wins entries to see if it
   works.
3. Rejoined all domain members with this problem to the domain
4. `net ads dns register` for all domain members with problems.

What should I do next to solve this netbios problem?

Comment: Thanks John K. We have a Samba domain member server running 3.5 that works perfectly. We only have one server running samba 3.0.33 - which I have shown above. I looked for the two strings that you mentioned in our samba logs but I cannot find them. Like I said, authentication and browsing works but members are not populated within the domain master browser.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any logs showing problems or errors with the member servers running Samba 3.0.33?  Is this problem, by chance, occurring only on the older version or are both version exhibiting this behavior?

I know there are known issues with how older versions of Samba handle authentication with Windows Server 2008 up to version 3.3  We've had issues with that exact version of Samba (3.0.33) and our solution was to simply upgrade to 3.5.  In our case, we would lose domain joins, or, just like you describe, the member server would not populate.

Errors we saw were "NT Missing Parameter," and "NT ACCESS DENIED" errors.